# npgsql with NetTopologySuite can't write 3D point

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, nettopologysuite

I'm trying to write a 3d point (and linestring) to a database table using npgsql with NetTopologySuite. I'm using last release (4.0.3), as apparently has resolved issue [#1906](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1906). My code:

```
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection ( "Host=localhost;Port=5433;Username=test;Password=test;Database=maindb" );
        conn.Open();
        conn.TypeMapper.UseNetTopologySuite( handleOrdinates: Ordinates.XYZ );
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand ( "INSERT INTO public.testtable (position) VALUES (@position)", conn );
        cmd.Parameters.Add ( "position", NpgsqlDbType.Geometry );
        NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point pp = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point ( 1, 2, 3 );
        cmd.Parameters["position"].Value = pp;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But this does not work, as inserts a plain 2D point into the table.

I'm using this versions of packages:

- Npgsql v4.0.3
- Npgsql.NetTopologySuite v1.0.2
- NetTopologySuite v1.15.1
- NetTopologySuite.IO.PostGis v1.15.0
- GeoApi.Core v1.7.5

Is there something wrong with configuration or have I to do some other things to make the 3D point to work?

P.S.: I've found a workaround that works, but sincerely that seems ugly:

```
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection ( "Host=localhost;Port=5433;Username=test;Password=test;Database=maindb" );
        conn.Open();
        conn.TypeMapper.UseNetTopologySuite( handleOrdinates: Ordinates.XYZ );
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand ( "INSERT INTO public.testtable (position) VALUES (@position)", conn );
        cmd.Parameters.Add ( "position", NpgsqlDbType.Text );
        NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point pp = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point ( 1, 2, 3 );
        cmd.Parameters["position"].Value = pp.ToString();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Can you confirm whether you can write a 2D point (i.e. remove the 3rd value)?

Comment: I confirm, 2D points are written just fine. Actually, when I try to write a 3D point, a 2D point is stored instead, stripping out the third coordinate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, issue has been resolved with last release of Npgsql (4.0.4) and Npgsql.NetTopologySuite (4.0.4)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you forgot to pass `Ordinates.XYZ` to `UseNetTopologySuite()`, as shown in [the Npgsql docs](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/nts.html#setup):

```
conn.TypeMapper.UseNetTopologySuite(handleOrdinates: Ordinates.XYZ);
```

Comment: Ok, that was a mistake. I forget that into the example, but I did try that in the production code and unfortunately does not work. For confirmation I tried that in the example provided too and does not change the issue.

Comment: I've changed the code to reflect the correct type mapper initialization